# horizontal ViewPager inside horizontal RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager, gridlayoutmanager

I have a recyclerview with GridLayoutManager and inside the item I'm using a ViewPager to show photos and I get the crash below:

> 02-28 14:58:56.618 30212-30212/ofeksprojects.ofek.com.nightout E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                    Process: ofeksprojects.ofek.com.nightout, PID: 30212
>                                                                                    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.widget.LinearLayout.getChildAt(int)' on a null object reference
>                                                                                        at eu.fiskur.simpleviewpager.SimpleViewPager.setIndicator(SimpleViewPager.java:217)
>                                                                                        at eu.fiskur.simpleviewpager.SimpleViewPager.onLayout(SimpleViewPager.java:243)
>                                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16694)
>                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5481)
>                                                                                        at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1495)
>                                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16694)
>                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5481)
>                                                                                        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
>                                                                                        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
>                                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16694)
>                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5481)
>                                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.layoutDecoratedWithMargins(RecyclerView.java:8994)
>                                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager.layoutChunk(GridLayoutManager.java:685)
>                                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1518)
>                                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:585)
>                                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(GridLayoutManager.java:170)
>                                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3719)
>                                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3436)
>                                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3988)
>                                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16694)
>                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5481)
>                                                                                        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1079)
>                                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16694)
>                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5481)
>                                                                                        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
>                                                                                        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
>                                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16694)
>                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5481)
>                                                                                        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1079)
>                                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16694)
>                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5481)
>                                                                                        at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.layoutChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:132)
>                                                                                        at android.support.design.widget.ViewOffsetBehavior.onLayoutChild(ViewOffsetBehavior.java:42)
>                                                                                        at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onLayoutChild(AppBarLayout.java:1361)
>                                                                                        at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:874)
>                                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16694)
>                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5481)
>                                                                                        at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1172)
>                                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16694)
>                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5481)
>                                                                                        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
>                                                                                        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
>                                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16694)
>                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5481)
>                                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
>                                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
>                                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
>                                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16694)
>                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5481)
>                                                                                        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
>                                                                                        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
>                                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16694)
>                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5481)
>                                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
>                                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
>                                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
>                                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16694)
>                                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5481

I remember I read it is a known issue because both the recyclerview and viewpager are scrolled horizontally but I cant find the solution. anyone who can put some light on it?

here is the code -

```
ublic class PlacesSearchAdapter extends BaseQuickAdapter<Place,PlacesSearchAdapter.PlaceViewHolder> {

private static String PLACE_PHOTOS_BASE_URL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?";
public PlacesSearchAdapter(@Nullable List<Place> data) {
    super(R.layout.place_item_base_layout,data);
}

@Override
protected void convert(PlaceViewHolder helper, Place item) {
    helper.nameTV.setText(item.getName());
    helper.addressTV.setText(item.getTextualAddress());
    loadThumbs(helper,item);
}

private void loadThumbs(PlaceViewHolder helper, Place item) {
    ArrayList<String> photosUrl = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Place.PlacePhoto photo:item.getPhotos()) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(PLACE_PHOTOS_BASE_URL);
        builder.append("maxwidth="+photo.getWidth());
        builder.append("&");
        builder.append("maxheight="+photo.getHeight());
        builder.append("&");
        builder.append("photoreference="+photo.getReference());

        photosUrl.add(builder.toString());
    }
    String[] photosArr = photosUrl.toArray(new String[photosUrl.size()]);
    helper.photosPager.setImageUrls(photosArr, new ImageURLLoader() {
        @Override
        public void loadImage(ImageView imageView, String url) {
            Picasso.with(imageView.getContext()).load(url).fit().into(imageView);
        }
    });
}

public class PlaceViewHolder extends BaseViewHolder {
    SimpleViewPager photosPager;
    TextView nameTV,addressTV;
    MaterialFavoriteButton favoriteButton;
    public PlaceViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        nameTV = view.findViewById(R.id.nameTV_placeAdapter);
        addressTV = view.findViewById(R.id.addressTV_placeAdapter);
        photosPager = view.findViewById(R.id.placeThumb_placeAdapter);
        int indicatorColor = Color.parseColor("#ffffff");
        int selectedIndicatorColor = Color.parseColor("#fff000");
        photosPager.showIndicator(indicatorColor, selectedIndicatorColor);

        favoriteButton = view.findViewById(R.id.favoriteButton_placeAdapter);

    }
}
```

}

and my onViewCreated() -

```
 public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    final CardView searchCard = view.findViewById(R.id.searchCard_searchFrag);
    placesRV = view.findViewById(R.id.resultList_searchFrag);
    placesRV.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(placesRV.getContext(),1,GridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false));
    assert getActivity()!=null;
    placesRV.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
    placesRV.getLayoutManager().setAutoMeasureEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Can you post your code? This is where things start to go sideways: eu.fiskur.simpleviewpager.SimpleViewPager.setIndicator

Comment: I've added the code